# Rock Paper Scissors Game. Trouble with defining terms

Tags: python

This is the largest program I've made so far my problem is that my program won't run because the variable cpu isn't defined. I've tried different approaches but still nothing. Here is my code, also is there anyway to shorten my code? I felt I made alot of repetitive lines. I suspect that my problem is in the def cpu_choice(). Also this program dosent seem to give any output after its done.

```
#This program will execute a Rock,Paper,Scissors Game.
import random
get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))
def cpu_choice():#This function is for the computer to get a option.
    list_option = [1 , 2, 3]
    cpu = random.choice(list_option)
    return(random.choice(list_option))
    if cpu == 1:
        cpu = "Rock"
    if cpu == 2:
        cpu = 'Paper'
    if cpu == 3:
        cpu = 'Scissor'
def compare(cpu,get):
    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
      if get == cpu:
          print('Its a tie!')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
            main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
          #Checks to see if it is a tie 
      elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Scissor':
          print('You win!')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
             #Compares when CPU picks Rock.
      elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Paper':
          print('You lose.')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False

      elif cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Rock':
          print('You win!')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
      elif cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Scissor':
          print('You lose.')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
      elif cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Paper':
          print('You win!')
    #This will decide the outcome when the computer picks paper.
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
      elif cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Rock':
          print('You lose.')
          again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
          if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
             main(cpu)
          if again == 'n' or 'N':
             again = False
    #This decides the outcome if the computer picks scissors.


def main(cpu,get):# Executes the programs and checks to see if the input is valid.
    print('Rock = 1')
    print('Paper = 2')
    print('Scissor = 3')
    again = 'y'

    while get < 1:
      get = int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    while get > 3:
      get= int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    if get == 1:
        get = "Rock"
    if get == 2:
        get = 'Paper'
    if get == 3:
        get = 'Scissor'
    cpu_choice()
    compare(cpu,get)
main(cpu,get)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More efficient choice comparison for Rock Paper Scissors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730900/more-efficient-choice-comparison-for-rock-paper-scissors)

Comment: Return exits a function all code behind return in a function is never executed

Comment: cpu is a local variable, and that is why the last line of your main gives an error. it cannot be passed to the compare function, as it is only a local variable in your cpu_choice function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cpu_choice should look like this:

```
def cpu_choice():#This function is for the computer to get a option.
    list_option = [1 , 2, 3]
    cpu = random.choice(list_option)
    if cpu == 1:
        cpu = "Rock"
    if cpu == 2:
        cpu = 'Paper'
    if cpu == 3:
        cpu = 'Scissor'
    return cpu
```

This is because a return will exit the function so any code behind a return statement in a function will never be executed.

Your main function should look like this:

```
def main(cpu,get):# Executes the programs and checks to see if the input is valid.
    print('Rock = 1')
    print('Paper = 2')
    print('Scissor = 3')
    again = 'y'

    while get < 1:
      get = int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    while get > 3:
      get= int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    if get == 1:
        get = "Rock"
    if get == 2:
        get = 'Paper'
    if get == 3:
        get = 'Scissor'

    compare(cpu,get)
```

You don't need to declare a cpu in your main function as you already pass a cpu to your main function.

Outside of your functions you will need this:

```
get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))
cpu = cpu_choice()
main(cpu,get)
```

Now your main function has all the parameters it needs. Note I placed `get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))` after the declaration of your functions. This is a common practice making understanding your code much easier.

**Qua Optimisation**

1. Pythons `random` can choose a random element from a list:
2. `Or`'s can be used to make one `elif` for if you win and 1 for if you lose.
3. Considering that you call `main()` from within `compare()` it is best for `main()` to have no parameters but rather get `get` and `cpu` in the main function
4. A `while` statement can have multiple comparisons.

An optimised code would look like this:

```
    import random

    def cpu_choice():
        list_option = ["Rock" , "Paper", "Scissor"]
        cpu = random.choice(list_option)
        return cpu

    def compare(cpu,get):
        if get == cpu:
            print('Its a tie!')
            again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
            if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
                main()
        elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Scissor' or cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Rock' or cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Paper':
            print('You lose.')
            again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
            if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
                main()
        elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Paper' or cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Scissor' or cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Rock':
            print('You win!')
            again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
            if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
                main()

    def main():
        print('Rock = 1')
        print('Paper = 2')
        print('Scissor = 3')
        get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))
        cpu = cpu_choice()

        while not 4 > get > 0:
          get = int(input('Enter a valid number.'))

        if get == 1:
            get = "Rock"
        if get == 2:
            get = 'Paper'
        if get == 3:
            get = 'Scissor'

        compare(cpu,get)

    main()
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed that problem but now I'm having trouble with getting output. After I enter in a number nothing happens.

Comment: @Janes this is probably because you have "get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))" this 2 times in your code. The first time at the very top, I just took it down to the bottom as function declaration should be the first thing after import.

Comment: @Janes Was my answer helpful? If yes please accept my answer for reputation sake

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your cpu_choice function to return a value. In addition, your return statement should also be removed, as explained in the comment next to it:

```
def cpu_choice(): #This function is for the computer to get a option.
    list_option = [1 , 2, 3]
    cpu = random.choice(list_option)
    #return(random.choice(list_option)) #This returns a number, but in your compare code you are comparing strings, so take this line out
    if cpu == 1:
        cpu = "Rock"
    if cpu == 2:
        cpu = 'Paper'
    if cpu == 3:
        cpu = 'Scissor'
    return cpu
```

in your main function, you can set another variable called cpu to the return value of your function called cpu_choice

```
def main(cpu,get): #Executes the programs and checks to see if the input is valid.
    print('Rock = 1')
    print('Paper = 2')
    print('Scissor = 3')
    again = 'y'

    while get < 1:
      get = int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    while get > 3:
      get= int(input('Enter a valid number.'))
    if get == 1:
        get = "Rock"
    if get == 2:
        get = 'Paper'
    if get == 3:
        get = 'Scissor'
    cpu = cpu_choice()
    compare(cpu,get)
```

Comment: edited, i didnt catch his return statement, as most people usually keep it at the end of their functions @TobiasWilfert

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it but now my problem is I get no output from the program.

Comment: @Janes without seeing you full code, i dont know where your mistake is. I suggest  printing out the cpu and get variables inside your compare function to see if the program gets to that function call successfully, and if it does, proceed to only check inside that function only

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom, you are calling main with the parameters 'cpu', which is undefined, and 'get', which is defined by user input at the top.  This program takes 1 input and prints an output - you don't need to feed the cpu parameter to main since it is generated from what the cpu_choice function returns.  Just get rid of that as a parameter and write cpu = cpu_choice() before you call compare, and have cpu_choice() return the cpu value.

Answer (score 0):

With a few corrections it's working: (read the comments)

```
import random

def cpu_choice():
    list_option = [1 , 2, 3]
    cpu = random.choice(list_option)
    if cpu == 1:
        cpu = "Rock"
    if cpu == 2:
        cpu = 'Paper'
    if cpu == 3:
        cpu = 'Scissor'
    return cpu   # the return goes here 

def compare(cpu,get):
    # you are using too many checks for again
    # I'm moving the again checks out of here
    # Moreover, all the results (win, lose) where wrong if you are 'get' 
    print("You -> " + get + "  -  " + cpu + " <- CPU")
    if get == cpu:
        print('Its a tie!')
    elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Scissor':
        print('You lose!')
    elif cpu == 'Rock' and get == 'Paper':
        print('You win.')
    elif cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Rock':
        print('You lose!')
    elif cpu == 'Paper' and get == 'Scissor':
        print('You win.')
    elif cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Paper':
        print('You lose!')
    elif cpu == 'Scissor' and get == 'Rock':
        print('You win.')

def game():   # Don't call it main please, and no need for the arguments

    print('Rock = 1')
    print('Paper = 2')
    print('Scissor = 3')

    get = int(input('Enter a number 1 to 3 as your choice.\n'))

    while (get < 1) or (get > 3):   # No need for two while loops
        get = int(input('Enter a valid number.'))

    if get == 1:
        get = "Rock"
    if get == 2:
        get = 'Paper'
    if get == 3:
        get = 'Scissor'

    # Or you can use this
    # symbols = ["Rock","Paper","Scissor"]
    # get = symbols[get-1]    # it's better if you don't call both variables 'get'

    cpu = cpu_choice()  # you need to assign a value to cpu here
    compare(cpu,get)

    # I put the again code here
    again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to quit.')
    if again in ['y','Y']:
        game()
    else:
        print("Bye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":   # This is the main
    game()
```

Comment: Hey there your comments were super helpful and your code was way cleaner then mine Thank you. Can you explain the line cpu= cpu_choice()? Why would I need to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: The function cpu_choice() returns a value ("Rock", "Paper" or "Scissor") and you want to "catch" it and assign it to a variable (cpu in this case) so you can then, in the next line, pass it as argument to the function compare(). You need to do this because inside the game() function you cannot see the variable cpu which is inside the cpu_choice() function, because it's not in its scope (and that's way you return its value at the end of the function). So if you don't do that, after the call to cpu_choice() there is no cpu variable and if you pass it to compare() you get an error.