# My JavaScript code for Rock, Paper, Scissor game is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript. I'm trying to make a Rock, Paper, Scissor game in Js.

```
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerSelection = prompt("Choose Rock, Paper, Scissor");
let choice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"];

function computerPlay(choice) {
    let computerChoice = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
    return computerChoice; 
}

let computerSelection = computerPlay(choice);

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        console.log (`It is a tie. Player ${playerScore} vs Computer ${computerScore}`);
    }
    
    else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") {
        computerScore++;
        console.log (`Computer won! Player ${playerScore} vs Computer ${computerScore}`);
    }
    
    else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissor") {
        computerScore++;
        console.log (`Computer won! Player ${playerScore} vs Computer ${computerScore}`);
    }
    
    else if (playerSelection === "scissor" && computerSelection === "rock") {
        computerScore++;
        console.log (`Computer won! Player ${playerScore} vs Computer ${computerScore}`);
    }
    
    else {
        playerScore++;
        console.log (`You won! Player ${playerScore} vs Computer ${computerScore}`);
    }
}

playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
```

But my code is not working as I was expecting. Whatever choice(Rock, Paper, Scissor) I give in prompt, it is only giving me a same result every time i.e. only else conditional statement is working.

Comment: [Not a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730900/more-efficient-choice-comparison-for-rock-paper-scissors), but it might give you some ideas ...

Comment: When you refresh the page for a prompt you reset the score to 0.

Answer (score 2):

after doing playerSelection.toLowerCase(); store it into same variable.

toLowerCase does not update anything inline in string, its just return the value, so you will have store the return value somewhere

```
playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
```

Also change the choice array to lower case

```
let choice = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
```

Comment: And `computerSelection` should also be changed to lower case.

Comment: I changed choice Array to lowercase and it worked. Damn, it was a silly mistake. Thankyou so much for help @RanjitSingh